# How to schedule task on Linux Desktop

Tags: bash, cron, ubuntu-mate, schedule, anacron

How to schedule task on Ubuntu Mate 20.04 Desktop, to run bash script.sh once a day on Tu/We/Thu/Fri/Sat, after laptop startup?

Note:
I can run job once a day by Anacron on laptop starup:

```
/etc/anacrontab
1       5       cron.data       /bin/sh /home/d/OneDrive/01_Data/cron_download.sh
```

And I would like to run it only Tu-Sat.

```
/etc/cron.data/anacron
0 0 * * 2-6   root    /script.sh
```

Not sure how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for advice, it is very simple, I want to run script.sh once a day on Tu/We/Thu/Fri/Sat after laptop start. I added Note to show what I tried, is it more clear?

Comment: Cron is not intended to do complex logic for you. You need TWO cron jobs: One daily, and one reboot.Both trigger a script that does your do-I-need-to-run? logic and then, if desirable, triggers your actual job. Alternately, you can use a systmd service and timer for this instead of cron.

Comment: @user535733  Thanks for info. What about Anacron, can I run by Anacron  cron task that is scheduled to run on (Tu-Sa) once a day ?

Comment: 5 minutes after boot:
@reeboot sleep 5m;/path/to/script

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this solution is the job should run only once a day, with @reboot  it will run every reboot

Comment: You can indeed use Anacron...but months from now (when you need to tweak your logic), will you remember how you did it?

Comment: First I need to know how to do it :) I write all in docs so it wont be forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

[Kalarm](https://apps.kde.org/en/kalarm) does the job, unfortunately for some reason it doesn't run httpio(asyncio) asynchronous web request in python, so if there is other solution it will be appreciated.